# Is node.js ready for big enterprise cloud applications?

Tags: node.js, jakarta-ee, cloud, npm, node-modules

Over a decade we have built our products in .NET or java technologies. These products were hosted on premise and there was no concept of a Saas as of now. 
Now, we are planning to build a product on cloud that is going to have more than 10,000 users operating on more than 500 forms and 200 reports. With this much, you can imagine the size of database and other things. We will need the application to scale accordingly. We need a responsive web application where all the tenants will have a customized solution for web and handheld platforms. We had shortlisted J2EE with hibernate and spring backed by a MySQL db. But then we came across this Node.js and Google's V8 engine. We are quite interested since it's new and ready for cloud and web and therefore, we are ready to invest in the developers.
I'm just keen to know how will this technology help in building such a big product.
Is there a good IDE that promises code maintainability as in Eclipse or VS?
Are there integrations or connectors ready for SAP, Oracle and other systems?
Are there tools for code templating and scaffolding for generating these many forms?
Do we have to use a different DB and not MySQL or SQLServer?
Would you recommend ORMs and which ones?
And is there a report generation tool like we have SSRS or JasperReports?

I know what node.js is. I just want few tips about it's ability to build enterprise level cloud apps. What would be the plus points of using node.js over Java? Or could it be a combined approach of both?

Comment: Very interesting question. I'll be happy if I get some answers.

Comment: Interesting question, but unfortunately off-topic. Try posting in chat?

Comment: Damn, I'd love to hear the answer to this question!